# How can I set some global functions/mixins in Quasar Vue V2 framework

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm using Quasar Framework V2 for a SPA and I need to create a class in which I can declare all the shared functions/methods on the app to reduce code writing.

For example, to show an alert from the Notify plugin you have to use this code:

```
$q.notify({
          message: 'Error',
          color: 'primary',
          actions: [
            { label: 'Dismiss', color: 'white', handler: () => { /* ... */ } }
          ]
        })
```

It's too long to write this in every event I want that notification to be called.
But I don´t know the right way to do this on Quasar.
**I tried using boot files but failed**

I just want to call `notifyError()` from a global class/mixin/boot or whatever.
Something like this:

```
const notifyError = () => {

$q.notify({
          message: 'Jim just pinged you.',
          color: 'primary',
          avatar: 'https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/boy-avatar.png',
          actions: [
            { label: 'Reply', color: 'yellow', handler: () => { /* ... */ } },
            { label: 'Dismiss', color: 'white', handler: () => { /* ... */ } }
          ]
        })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a utility for notifications like this:

```
// If you're not using Quasar CLI, you probably have a quasar.js file that you'll need to import inside main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Quasar, Notify } from 'quasar';

Vue.use(Quasar, {
  // You can configure here how notify works
  config: {
    notify: {
    position: 'top-right',
    timeout: 2000,
  },
  // You need to import the plugin
  plugins: {
    Notify,
  },
});
```

---

```
// If you're using Quasar CLI, you need to add the Notify plugin in quasar.conf.js
module.exports = function () {
  return {
    framework: {
      plugins: [
        'Notify',
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

---

```
// util/notify.js
import { Notify } from 'quasar';

const error = (message) => {
  Notify.create({
    message,
    color: 'primary',
    actions: [
      { label: 'Dismiss', color: 'white', handler: () => { /* ... */ } },
    ],
  });
};

const primary = (message) => {
  Notify.create({
    message,
    color: 'primary',
    avatar: 'https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/boy-avatar.png',
    actions: [
      { label: 'Reply', color: 'yellow', handler: () => { /* ... */ } },
      { label: 'Dismiss', color: 'white', handler: () => { /* ... */ } },
    ],
  });
};

export default {
  error,
  primary,
};
```

---

```
// Home.vue
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
import notify from '@/notify';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  async created() {
    notify.primary('message');
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in Quasar framework there is no access to main.js 
I think this can be refactored to use it on some boot file,

Comment: I updated my answer. You'll need to update `quasar.conf.js` to load the Notify plugin. Create that `util/notify` file or however you like to name it and you can import it in any component. You don't need a boot file.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In quasar there is boot folder you can create your own file for example :

```
// src/boot/Notify.js


import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { Notify} from 'quasar'
export default boot(async ({ app }) => {   
  const notifyError = () => {

        Notify.create({
          message: 'Jim just pinged you.',
          color: 'primary',
          avatar: 'https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/boy-avatar.png',
          actions: [
              { label: 'Reply', color: 'yellow', handler: () => { /* ... */ } },
              { label: 'Dismiss', color: 'white', handler: () => { /* ... */ } }
            ]
          })

  }

 app.config.globalProperties.$notifyError = notifyError 
}
```

Second  you should Add this file in **quasar.conf.js**

```
boot: [
      'i18n',//already exist
      'axios',//already exist
      'Notify'//NEW : Our File Name  in boot folder 
    ],
```

Now you can access  this function in your component like that :

```
this.$notifyError()
```

in the same way, you can create how many functions you want and also boot files ...

Comment: "This" is undefined in my component, any suggestion?

Comment: are you accessing the "this" inside an arrow function ?